# Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've been using this script for the last two years but it stopped working two months ago with the mention : failed while accessing document with id, is there something that changed with Google?

```
function copyHoraireJourCovid(){
copySchedule(true);
}

function copyHoraireNuitCovid(){
copySchedule(false);
}

function copySchedule(jourCovid){
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
//var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1i-p3X1Y13NgYPNZrl34yHaIOPwm9t8ATsQbt995S4os'); // test
//var destSheet = destination.getSheetByName('DATA'); // test
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Aym8F6kHIYaGuYbHyFxiiTC9MUEqHMaLTCvnEBl4a-k');

if (jourCovid)
{
var destSheet = getSheetById(destination, 347147217);

// remove temp sheet
if (destination.getSheetByName("TEMP-Jour-Covid") != null)
{
destination.deleteSheet(destination.getSheetByName("TEMP-Jour-Covid"));
}
var newData = source.copyTo(destination).setName("TEMP-Jour-Covid");
}
else // nuitCovid
{
var destSheet = getSheetById(destination, 1438310663);

// remove temp sheet
if (destination.getSheetByName("TEMP-NUIT-COVID") != null)
{
destination.deleteSheet(destination.getSheetByName("TEMP-NUIT-COVID"));
}
var newData = source.copyTo(destination).setName("TEMP-NUIT-COVID");
}

// copy new data
var sourceRange = newData.getDataRange();//getRange(1, 1, 100, 100);
var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
var rangeDest = destSheet.getRange(sourceRange.getA1Notation());

// clear old data
destSheet.clear();

// copy values
rangeDest.setValues(sourceValues);

sourceRange.copyFormatToRange(destSheet,1, 1, 1, 1); // copy format (bold, background color...)
sourceRange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false); // copy columns width

// copy rows heights
var row_heights = getRowHeights(sourceRange);
var destinationRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getRange(1,1).getRow(),
destSheet.getRange(1,1).getColumn(),
sourceRange.getHeight());
var set_row_heights = setRowHeights(row_heights,destinationRange);

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a VERY widespread problem. It seems to have started early March 2021. This item on Google Doc Editors Help [Google Script failure: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/101741111/google-script-failure-service-spreadsheets-failed-while-accessing-document-with-id?hl=en) provides a good summary of the issue, the issue tracker. It also includes a link to a workaround.

This is the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182701055?pli=1). Add a comment to increase the weight of support.